# Fiberwise isomorphism of number rings $\mathcal{O}_E\otimes \mathbb{F}_p\cong \mathcal{O}_F\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Are there two different number fields $E$ and $F$ such that $\mathcal{O}_E\otimes \mathbb{F}_p\cong \mathcal{O}_F\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$ for all primes $p$?

Comment: Apparently not, by Bauer's theorem. See p. 4 here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/cfthistory.pdf and this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/180337/3847

Comment: Sorry, that's only for $E$ and $F$ Galois.

Comment: What does "fiberwise" mean in the subject?

Comment: @LSpice It makes sense if you consider the map $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal O_K\to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$ - the ring $\mathcal O_K\otimes\mathbb F_p$ is its fiber over the prime $p$. (though I suppose we have to ignore the fiber over the generic point for this question to be nontrivial)

Answer (score 4):

The entirety of the factorization of primes in a number field $K$ is encoded in its Dedekind zeta function. Therefore if two number fields $E,F$ have coinciding Dedekind zeta functions, the rings $\mathcal O_E\otimes\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathcal O_E\otimes\mathbb F_p$ are isomorphic. Fields with this property are called *arithmetically equivalent*, and it turns out that there exist pairs of such fields which are not isomorphic. You can find some further information in answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/80403/30186).

Comment: Why does the Dedekind zeta function determine the isomorphism type of $\mathcal{O}_E\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$ at ramified primes $p$?

Comment: @Aurel Hm, on second thought I realize this is not so immediate - you can easily recover the number of distinct prime factors of $p$ in $\mathcal O_E$ as well as their inertia degree, but it is unclear to me how to recover ramification from it. I think these can be recovered from the representation $\mathbb C[G/H]$ as in the linked question, so the pairs of fields constructed there should work too, but I will have to think about it more.